# Smooth shading not applying in renders

Tags: rendering, objects

I found that after I finished modeling my base, adding materials, and adding smooth shading that once I proceeded to render my model the everything, but the smooth shading applied.

It is the most peculiar occurrence for I have applied smooth shading to other models and once I rendered those the smooth shading worked. Also, on the blender user manual the author states that smooth shading applies to the viewport and the render.

I have researched the problem and have found nothing, and my bewilderment continues to increase. I am using Blender version 2.93.4 and I have also attached two photos of my problem.

I have also update blender from 2.93.4 to 2.93.6 and the problem continues to persist.

First photo, the rendered model with the recurring problem of not applying smooth shading.

[image]

Original model, not rendered, complete with materials and smooth shading, no problem here.
[image]

[image]

Comment: How can I add the file to the post to help people answer the question better?

Comment: To upload a file use either [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) or [pasteall](https://pasteall.org/blend/). [Edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/244817/edit) the link to your file into your question.

Comment: are you using a subdivision surface modifier on the object?  If so, check its settings to make sure the number of subdivisions is > 0 for rendering.

Comment: Yes, I am using a subdivision surface modifier with a subdivision count greater than 0.

Comment: I fixed it!! The problem was the shading language on the subdivision surface modifier.